# Can you keg your homebrew in a cleaning keg?

Tags: kegging

I have been brewing beer for a couple of months now. I currently have a beer line and tap in my garage that has a cleaning keg for running cleaning solution through the lines.

I was just wondering if it was possible to keg your homebrew in a cleaning keg as I have access to a 20l cleaning keg?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be an issue with it, but make sure the keg is cleaned before you fill it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do so, but there is an increased risk of chemical contamination. You will have to ensure the cleaning keg is very throughly cleaned as even small amounts of cleaning solution and be very dangerous.